# Remove attribute from object recursivly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I got a JSON string, which I would like to strip from some values. The problem is that the JSON object can contain child objects, which if they exist, I want to strip of the same sort of values (based on the key).

For example, I got this:

```
{
    Title: "test",
    Created: "2013-01-01",
    ID: 1
    Child: {
        Title: "Test 2",
        Created: "2013-01-02",
        ID: 2,
        RandomName: {
            Title: "Test 3",
            Created: "2013-01-05",
            ID:3
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to remove the key "Created" from the objects and from all the child objects. Is there an easy way to achieve this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tobias' answer, I modified the code to support child arrays etc. too. Mind you, I am fairly new to Ruby, so I am not sure this is a 100% complete.

The keysToRemove parameter is an array which contains the names of the keys I want to remove.

```
def remove_recursive(hash, keysToRemove)
    if hash.kind_of?(Array)
      hash.each do |h|
        remove_recursive(h, keysToRemove)
      end
    elsif hash.kind_of?(Hash)
      hash.each do |key, value|
        if keysToRemove.include?(key)
          hash.delete(key)
        else
          remove_recursive(hash[key], keysToRemove)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! It started crashing on me at first, then I remembered that my JSON collection also had arrays in them.

Comment: :D Yeah, sorry about that - I figured your JSON string would match the given example, so I didn't add that. (Trying to keep the code simple and giving you a nudge into the right direction :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can write a helper that calls the nested element recursively (example assuming you parsed the JSON to a hash)

```
def remove_recursive(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    hash.delete(key) if key == "Created"
    remove_recursive(hash[key]) if hash[key].kind_of?(Hash)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a proc if you don't want to have a method just for this.

```
require 'json'

json_string = '{
    "Title": "test",
    "Created": "2013-01-01",
    "ID": 1,
    "Child": {
        "Title": "Test 2",
        "Created": "2013-01-02",
        "ID": 2,
        "RandomName": {
            "Title": "Test 3",
            "Created": "2013-01-05",
            "ID": 3
        }
    }
}'


without_fields = proc do |h, *fields|
  h = h.reject {|k,_| fields.include?(k) }
  h.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      h[k] = without_fields.call(v, *fields)
    end
  end
  h
end

json_obj = JSON.load(json_string)
cleaned_obj = without_fields.call(json_obj, 'Created')
JSON.dump(cleaned_obj)
# => "{\"Title\":\"test\",\"ID\":1,\"Child\":{\"Title\":\"Test 2\",\"ID\":2,\"RandomName\":{\"Title\":\"Test 3\",\"ID\":3}}}"
```